# c# Calling an method from an object

Tags: c#, object, methods, instance

So I roughly got this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    GameEngine engine;
    public Form1()
    {
        engine = new GameEngine();
    }

    public void repaint()
    {

    }
}

class GameEngine
{
    public void update()
    {

    }
}
```

Now i wanna add something to the update() method, which makes it call the repaint() method, inside of that instance of the Form1 class, in which the respective object of the GameEngine class was created.

In java i could've done it like this

```
        engine = new GameEngine()
        {
            public void repaintCaller()
            {
                repaint();
            }
        };
```

and call repaintCaller() in the update() method, but that doesn't work in c#, now what is the equilvalent way to do this in c#?

Comment: I think your question is sort of againts the Object Oriented Principles that is C#. You can give GameEngine a reference to Form but I think this would be bad design. Having a third class that connects between them seems wiser

Answer (score 0):

One way to have it is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    GameEngine engine;
    public Form1()
    {
        engine = new GameEngine();
        engine.update(this);
    }

    public void repaint()
    {

    }
}

class GameEngine
{
    public void update(Form1 form)
    {
        form.repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass to the `GameEngine.update` method an **Action** delegate to the `repaint` method in the form instance

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    GameEngine engine;
    public Form1()
    {
        engine = new GameEngine();
        // I put the call here for demo purpose,
        // of course you call the engine.update 
        // method when you need and where you want 
        engine.update(repaint)
    }

    public void repaint()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("repaint called in the Form1 instance");
    }
}

class GameEngine
{
    public void update(Action clientUpdate)
    {
       if(clientUpdate != null)
          clientUpdate.Invoke();
          // or just... clientUpdate();
    }
}
```

The [parameterless Action delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) in C# is a way to pass, as parameter, a method (repaint) to the called method (update). Of course, you could pass the whole Form1 instance to the update but this approach binds the GameEngine class to the Form1 class. With the Action approach you are free from this coupling and you could pass any other method that returns void and doesn't take any parameter defined in any class of your program. This frees your GameEngine.update method from any specific bind to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like that

```
class GameEngine
{
    public void update(ref Form1 caller)
    {
        caller.Refresh() //msdn says "Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child controls."
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [...]
    engine = new GameEngine()
    engine.update(ref This)
}
```

I'm not sure of anything, i'm not used to C#.
I just hope it will help a bit :)

Comment: Any reason why you pass the form using the ref keyword?

Answer (score 0):

You can also set Events from your form, like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    GameEngine engine;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        engine = new GameEngine();
        engine.repaintRequired += engine_repaintRequired;
        engine.update();
    }

    private void engine_repaintRequired(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        repaint();
    }

    public void repaint()
    {
        Console.Write("repaint");
    }
}

class GameEngine
{
    public event EventHandler repaintRequired;

    public void update()
    {
        onRepaintRequired();
    }

    private void onRepaintRequired()
    {
        if (repaintRequired != null)
            repaintRequired(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```